# Viewing changes in context with magit

Tags: git, emacs, magit

Consider a `magit` session started with only the two [recommended](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Getting-Started.html#Getting-Started) keybinding adjustments.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x g") 'magit-status)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M-g") 'magit-dispatch)
```

Now suppose that in this session I am merely perusing a repository, without the change/stage/commit sequence. Now I reach a `file.c`

```
// a: This line existed in commit A.
// a: This line existed in commit A.
// b: This is a new line added in commit B.
// b: This is a new line added in commit B.
```

To understand what has been done at each commit, I go through `git checkout` incrementally.

When at commit `B`, I'd like to see in context that the two lines (b above) are newly inserted, perhaps by a highlighted background, or by a margin indicator.

Is viewing changes in context possible with `magit`, or is `git diff` the best one can do?

Without `magit` [diff-hl-flydiff](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl/blob/master/diff-hl-flydiff.el) can already show how the current file is different from the repo. I'm here asking whether viewing the changes during a series of `git checkout` is possible, with `diff-hl-flydiff` if it can coexist nicely with `magit`, or without if this is built into `magit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to `git checkout` anything.

I suggest using <kbd>e</kbd> to invoke `magit-ediff-dwim` for the commit you are interested in (or <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to invoke `magit-ediff-show-commit`).  If the commit involves more than one file, it'll prompt you (with completion) for the file to diff.  Then it'll jump into ediff where you can peruse the changes for that commit diff in context.

If you view the log for just one file, using <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>M-g</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `magit-log-buffer-file`) then the Magit will assume you want to ediff that same file, and will not prompt you.

To learn how to use ediff: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(ediff)`

Comment: Nice. Perhaps the only catch is that if you're presenting your changes to an audience, and one block is large but you'd like to discuss elements of it on the fly, you'd have to adjust your region's colors carefully so that they remain visible (perhaps after going through a projector) on top of ediff's colors, as well as go out of the ediff context (by M-<backquote>) to discuss a subset of a block, and then back in to continue.